# Change package global variable

Tags: r, global-variables, reticulate

Is it possible to change a global variable which is visible only within a package?:

```
library(reticulate)

# access the variable - works
reticulate:::.globals$use_python_versions

# change the variable - doesn't work
reticulate:::.globals$use_python_versions = 'my_python_version/python'
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but check the `use_python` function which is intended to set the python version.

Answer (score 0):

```
assign('use_python_versions','my_python_version/python', env=reticulate:::.globals)
```